# MySql High CPU Low memory utilization

Tags: mysql, performance-tuning, database-performance

I am facing an issue with MySQL server. I am not a primary DB admin, so i might need some assistance in tuning DB.

The CPU Utilization shoots up way beyond expectations. It just hovers around 70-90% of CPU. Where as the memory utilization levels are less than One GB.
Memory at MySQL disposal is 8GB - 10GB.

i have increased the size of the most common variables recommended in serverfault, stackoverflow and others. However still the issue with High CPU and too low memory utilization still persists.

Attaching the config. Any recommendations. 
Application does read and write to database. Total number of entries written to db in each run are close to 200K. Each run is currently taking around 30 min. 
Any inputs are highly appreciated. Thank you.

Disk is an SSD, which is running at 30-40% utilization levels

Variable_name   Value

- Bytes_received   1414
- Bytes_sent   560672
- Com_admin_commands   25
- Com_change_db    1
- Com_delete   1
- Com_select   5
- Com_set_option   1
- Com_show_databases   1
- Com_show_events  1
- Com_show_function_status 2
- Com_show_procedure_status    2
- Connections  1004
- Created_tmp_disk_tables  29
- Created_tmp_files    7
- Created_tmp_tables   136
- Delayed_errors   0
- Delayed_insert_threads   0
- Delayed_writes   0
- Flush_commands   1
- Handler_commit   2
- Handler_delete   62432
- Handler_discover 0
- Handler_external_lock    18
- Handler_mrr_init 0
- Handler_prepare  0
- Handler_read_first   14
- Handler_read_key 11
- Handler_read_last    0
- Handler_read_next    216
- Handler_read_prev    0
- Handler_read_rnd 0
- Handler_read_rnd_next    70195
- Handler_rollback 0
- Handler_savepoint    0
- Handler_savepoint_rollback   0
- Handler_update   0
- Handler_write    2373
- Innodb_buffer_pool_dump_status   Dumping of buffer pool not started
- Innodb_buffer_pool_load_status   Buffer pool(s) load completed at 161230   - 3:53:32
- Innodb_buffer_pool_resize_status
- Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_data    20100
- Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_data    329318400
- Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty   2652
- Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_dirty   43450368
- Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed 7786
- Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free    372888
- Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_misc    228
- Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total   393216
- Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_rnd    0
- Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead    255
- Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_evicted    0
- Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests 3002463794
- Innodb_buffer_pool_reads 17421
- Innodb_buffer_pool_wait_free 0
- Innodb_buffer_pool_write_requests    6474793
- Innodb_data_fsyncs   292991
- Innodb_data_pending_fsyncs   1
- Innodb_data_pending_reads    0
- Innodb_data_pending_writes   0
- Innodb_data_read 289673728
- Innodb_data_reads    22831
- Innodb_data_writes   299547
- Innodb_data_written  1024508928
- Innodb_dblwr_pages_written   7593
- Innodb_dblwr_writes  993
- Innodb_log_waits 0
- Innodb_log_write_requests    760884
- Innodb_log_writes    290702
- Innodb_os_log_fsyncs 290737
- Innodb_os_log_pending_fsyncs 1
- Innodb_os_log_pending_writes 0
- Innodb_os_log_written    772521472
- Innodb_page_size 16384
- Innodb_pages_created 2425
- Innodb_pages_read    17675
- Innodb_pages_written 7786
- Innodb_row_lock_current_waits    0
- Innodb_row_lock_time 0
- Innodb_row_lock_time_avg 0
- Innodb_row_lock_time_max 0
- Innodb_row_lock_waits    0
- Innodb_rows_deleted  62432
- Innodb_rows_inserted 162705
- Innodb_rows_read 2421592738
- Innodb_rows_updated  794937
- Innodb_num_open_files    3000
- Innodb_truncated_status_writes   0
- Innodb_available_undo_logs   128
- Key_blocks_not_flushed   0
- Key_blocks_unused    3429467
- Key_blocks_used  5
- Key_read_requests    22
- Key_reads    5
- Key_write_requests   0
- Key_writes   0
- Last_query_cost  0
- Last_query_partial_plans 0
- Locked_connects  0
- Max_execution_time_exceeded  0
- Max_execution_time_set   0
- Max_execution_time_set_failed    0
- Max_used_connections 60
- Max_used_connections_time    12/30/2016 3:55
- Not_flushed_delayed_rows 0
- Ongoing_anonymous_transaction_count  0
- Open_files   18
- Open_streams 0
- Open_table_definitions   1400
- Open_tables  786
- Opened_files 15589
- Opened_table_definitions 4761
- Opened_tables    4763
- Queries  2148749
- Questions    22
- Select_scan  15
- Table_locks_immediate    108
- Table_locks_waited   0
- Table_open_cache_hits    5
- Table_open_cache_misses  4763
- Table_open_cache_overflows   4577
- Tc_log_max_pages_used    0
- Tc_log_page_size 0
- Tc_log_page_waits    0
- Threads_cached   0
- Threads_connected    60
- Threads_created  60
- Threads_running  56
- Uptime   1197
- Uptime_since_flush_status    1197

Comment: Well, have you profiled your database queries to ensure you have created proper indices? What iowait are you seeing?

Comment: 30-40% doesn't mean anything...what CPU iowait (if any) are you seeing?

Comment: Disk is a SSD. SSD utilization is 20-40% max. Minimum falls to ~5% too sometimes. I hope this is the expected answer.

Comment: You don't seem to have much of any caching enabled. Do some basic MySQL tuning and come back in a couple of days.

Comment: i am using transactions in code, so i didnt enable caching to ensure data consistency. Any suggestions on what needs to be changed?

Comment: I am on windows. getting io data seems not that easy when compared to linux. Trying to get it.

Comment: Use the slow query log and query profiling to determine what is taking the most time. Read the manual regarding optimization, especially buffering and caching. Use perfmon to get storage performance counters on Windows.

Comment: We can not see your configuration file.

Comment: @kris123456  If you do not post your complete my.cnf/ini we will not be in a position to offer any suggestions.  More questions would be answered if you could also post complete results of SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;   Then we would know how many threads are cached, data is cached, how you have changed io_capacities and max's, just tons of things to consider.  Need your assistance, please.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not allowed to. Sorry.